# Variable Global is not changed

Tags: apex, method, boolean

Start static variable as true on first mute method to false

I would like the second method to inherit the value of the first and not the global value

calling the public method I want the boolean to receive the value of the private method

```
public class Test{
    private static Boolean varBool= true;

    private static void fistMethod(){

        varBool= true;

    }  
    public static void secondMethod(){
        varBool;
       //This variable return true value
    }
}
```

Comment: You are setting a value to `true` twice. I'm not sure what behavior you are looking for other than getting back `true`. Could you clarify by an [edit], please? N.b. Apex does not have true global variables; this is a static variable.

Comment: calling the public method I want the boolean to receive the value of the private method

Comment: You need an edit here, but it sounds like you're trying to do this in secondMethod
Boolean localVarBool = firstMethod();

The problem is your firstMethod is a void return, so it can't get the value from that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you're attempting to do from the comments.  This exposes a public method that grabs the internal variable from a private static method which gets it from the private static variable.

```
public class Demo {
    private static Boolean varBool= true;

    private static Boolean firstMethod(){
        return varBool;
    }  
    public static void secondMethod(){
        Boolean localVarBool = firstMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, don't name classes Test if you can help it.  There is a system class named Test and it will interfere with test classes calling test methods (unless they fixed that weird ability).

Comment: I tend to prefer `Demo` as it is *very* clear what your intentions are.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I like that idea.  I copy/pasted the original and changed it to not somewhat lazily heh.  I've updated with demo.